# Code suddenly works after clicking Run in JSFiddle. What?

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas

I made a jsFiddle which demonstrates pixel manipulation in JavaScript. It works perfectly fine in Chrome. Then I moved to test it on Firefox.

It doesn't work and it threw an error:

> `IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount`

This confuses me. But wait, there's more.

When I click `Run` again, the code suddenly works. I don't know what sorcery is this, or it's just some weird Firefox bug.

You can see the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/RdK7H/
When you are in jsFiddle, click on Select File and select a PNG file. You should see the code is not working. Then you click Run. Do the same thing again, and it suddenly works.

There are also some problems in some of the functions in Firefox which also frustrated me, however it is not part of this question.

If you need to know, I'm using Firefox 26.0.

Comment: +1 for "I don't know what sorcery is this" hehe :D

Comment: In safari, I see that error in the console on 1st load and when I hit run.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird - I didn't test on Safari, but I assume it should work as well since it's also using WebKit.

Comment: If I subtrack 1 from the width and height in that call, the error goes away.  I know it's not an answer, but I find that odd.

Comment: @BarbaraLaird - Fun experiment to do: If you now remove `-1` and click `Run`, it will still work.

Comment: @aldanux - It's still not working: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ySPGM.png

Comment: yes.. I see this was strange for me too now...

Comment: Who downvoted the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your image hasn't completed loading yet so the default width and height of the image is returned (both 0). As you cannot use 0 for the width and height of `getImageData()` you get an error.

> When I click Run again, the code suddenly works. I don't know what
>   sorcery is this, or it's just some weird Firefox bug.

It's because the image is now in the cache and the browser happens to be able to provide it before you attempt to read its width and height (no, the bug is in *your* code :-) ).

Handling image loading with a busy loop and a timeout value is begging to fail.

Make sure you add an `onload` handler to the image (this may require you to refactor the code a bit to support a callback (or promise) and the return value won't be valid for the same reason as the error):

```
getRGBArray: function(uri, callback){  /// add parameter for callback here
    var image = new Image();

    image.onload = imageLoaded;        /// add an onload handler here

    image.src = uri;

    function imageLoaded() {
        //var t = Date.now();
        //while(Date.now() - t < 3000 && !image.width);

        var width = this.width,   /// replace image with this to be sure you
            height = this.height, /// ..are dealing with the correct image in
            canvas = $("<canvas>").attr({ /// ..case you load several ones..
                width: width,
                height: height
            }).appendTo("body"),
            ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");

        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data;

        ...

        callback(imgData);  /// example of callback
    }
...
}
```

Optionally separate the image loading so you can call this function without relying on if the image has loaded or not.

**Update**

As briefly mentioned you can separate the image loading from the your main code. For example - instead of loading your image in the `getRGBArray()` function, pre-load it somewhere else in the code and pass the image as an argument instead (callback cannot be avoided but you can keep your original code synchronous after the loading point):

```
function loadImage(url, callback) {

    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        callback(this);
    }
    image.src = uri;
}
```

Then call it for example like this:

```
loadImage(url, readyToGo);

function readyToGo(image) {

    var pixels = getRGBArray(image);
    ...
}
```

A small modification in the original function to make it use the passed image instead of url:

```
getRGBArray: function(image){

    var width = image.width,
        height = image.height,
        canvas = $("<canvas>").attr({
                width: width,
                height: height
            }).appendTo("body"),
            ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");

        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data;

        ...

        return opt;
    }
...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using a callback function? Using callback is of course guaranteed to work but I don't really like callbacks... They kinda suck because then I will have to wrap the rest of everything into a function.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 unfortunately no, all async calls (such as image loading) will require this.

Comment: Or is there another way to convert datauri into an RGB array?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 not with natvie HTML5 but it's not the RGB converting part that is the problem as this is synchronous. It's the image loading (which would be the case for any other solution as well). What you can do is to separate the image loading from your function and instead pass the image as an argument. That way your main code can stay synchronous.

Comment: Actually `getRGBArray` accepts a dataURI string, loads it as an image and puts it into a canvas, and extracts the RGB values from it. So I was guessing if there's any way to extracts the RGB values *without* loading it as an image.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 data-uri is just a base-64 encoded image file with a header which means you add a couple of extra steps (stripping of header and base-64 decoding) if you wanted to decode a file format at low-level. In any case, the answer given is correct in regards to the problem so please consider up-voting/accepting :)

Comment: Definitely. I might just have to change my code a little bit to make it to work with callbacks then (although I hate callbacks.)